# Phantom margin in recyclerview

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview, margins

I'm trying to set recyclerview item xml with google guidelines, and when i see preview in android studio - thats OK, actually margins alright. 
But when I'm starting app on real device (htc one s - 4.1.1 api 16) there are additional margins, which i have no idea to delete. Help me please

There are xml of recycler item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="88dp"
android:id="@+id/Item"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_recycler_item"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="blah"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="blah"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="13:00 - 14:00 14.03.2016"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />
```

There are code from layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fragments.FragmentTask">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

minsdk of my app - 11

 I've delete all margins and paddings from there, but problem not solved - phantom magrins exists

Whats wrong?

Comment: Why android:layout_height="88dp" instead of 88dp use wrap_content and then run the code

Comment: because google guideline tells that tile height on three-line list must be 88dp. So i deleted it recently and make "wrap_content". No result

Comment: Try using wrap_content because 88dp will look same in different devices

Comment: Go to dimens.xml  or search activity_vertical_margin or activity_horizontal_margin.Set them to 0dp.

Comment: @Rakshit Nawani I made it. No result. Phantom margins are here

Comment: @tiny sunlight Thank you Android guru))) It works!

Comment: It's default dimens after you create a new project.

Comment: @tinysunlight so can you help me one more time? when I make fixed tile height (88dp) when i set up paddings(left/right - 16dp, top-16dp, bottom-20dp) - third textview is invisible, or half-eated. How fix it?

Comment: You shouldn't use fixed 88dp height.Can you provide the gruideline you follow?

Comment: @tinysunlight https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/lists.html#lists-specs    scroll it to three-line-list

Comment: Do you use the same textSize with it?You needn't to follow it completely.

Comment: @tinysunlight yep, see the textsize in my xml file. 14 and 16 sp

Comment: Use dp instead of sp.Can you provide a screenshot?It is no need to follow every guideline.

Comment: @tinysunlight   I'll follow your advice) i set tile height 95dp and its all good

Comment: You needn't to set a fixed height ,just use wrap_content.

Comment: @tinysunlight i need all items same height to be ergonomic. so i have to fix height

Comment: What's the meaning of all items same height to be ergonomic?